# Get MNC, MCC, LAC and CID from mobile number

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to create an Android application that shows location of a given mobile number in map. I have found some services:

- https://unwiredlabs.com/api
- http://opencellid.org

that returns latitude and longitude based on MNC, MCC, LAC and CID

There is also [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) that returns latitude, longitude based on MNC, MCC, LAC and CID.

Therefore, I need this MNC, MCC, LAC and CID information from a given number. I have found that this [Andoid API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) returns the current device's cellular information.

Is there any Android API or third party service which returns cellular information based on the number. A free third party service is desirable, since I am willing to put the Android app in Google Play for free.

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

You can't because the data of incomming call contains only the number as string, and by sms ? also no because the user data header of the message can be null !!!

If you develop a current location application, it can be used only by the owner of the cell phone.

In the other hand, there are some developer who want to use the AT command to request the call but the only data comes with a call is only the number and only the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the MNC and MCC codes simply over the internet. Check out this link.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code

But sorry can't help you with LAC and CID.